# Creating Smart pointer of the object itself (this) in its constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, smart-pointers

So lets say I have

```cpp
class A
{

    A(std::vector<std::shared_pointer<A>> &a_vec)
    {
        auto shared_ptr = std::make_shared<A>(*this);
        a_vec.pushback<shared_ptr>;
    {
};
class B
{
std::vector<std::shared_pointer<A>> a_vector_;
    void constructA()
    {
        created_A = make_shared<A>(a_vector_);
    }
}
```

So Im creating a method for B which creates an A and the A pushes itself to the vector B provides.

And on paper this dependancy works like I expected to, atleast I thought it was until I realised the `a_vec.pushback<this*>;` is not very dependable.

When I have more code inbetween the push and the shared pointer initialisation as such

```cpp
    A(std::vector<std::shared_pointer<A>> a_vec)
    {
        auto shared_ptr = std::make_shared<A>(*this);
        
        //insert more code here

        a_vec.pushback<shared_ptr>;
    {
```

It seems that the initialisations and other stuff I do in there isn't reflected to the pointer the shared pointer is pointing. Whats the cause of this and is there a way to fix it? Also is there a reason this would be a bad practice to use?

Comment: `std::make_shared<A>(*this);` is creating a `shared_ptr` from a copy of `this`. Why are you trying to do that? Why should it be `A` responsibility to put itself in a vector and not `B` responsibility to create `A` and manage its lifetime (in vector or not)?

Comment: `A` pushes itself into a **copy** of the vector that `B` provides, then discards the copy. The constructor should take the vector by reference.

Comment: Cause in my main code I have A creating another class which A creates which also needs the same pointer, so I thought since A is the class thats in the middle it could maybe do it in such a manner.

Comment: Sorry it does normally I forgot it here let me edit and fix that.

Comment: What you want could only be possible if `A` was created with raw `new A` (or using `shared_ptr` with an empty deleter), but that's *very* questionable. A class normally should not care how it is stored, that's the problem of the owner of the class. I'd recommend you describe your actual problem in detail (including [mcve] of code) and you will probably get better answers.

Comment: Let me explain it very simple, When A is constructed it constructs B and B constructs C, I want to store the same shared pointer to B in both A and C and I want this shared pointer to be the same in both A and C.

Answer (score 0):

One of the challenges when you are programming in C++ is to understand object lifetime. So it is better to make object creation and destruction as clear as possible.

As I understood your case is to memoize "automagically" all created objects. It is easier to do using "factory method" constructA

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
};

class B//AInstanceFactory - is a better name
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> a_instances;

public:
    void constructA()
    {
        a_instances.push_back(std::make_shared<A>());
    }

    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& getAInstances() {
        return a_instances;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;

    b.constructA();

    std::cout << b.getAInstances().size() << "\n";

    b.constructA();

    std::cout << b.getAInstances().size() << "\n";
}
```

[WRONG PATH]
It is possible to make object which aware of shared_ptr/weak_ptr: use template std::enable_shared_from_this.
In that case your code might be following,:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    A(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& a_vec)
    {
        a_vec.push_back(shared_from_this());//bad_weak_ptr here!!!!
    }
};

class B
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> a_vector_;

public:
    void constructA()
    {
        auto a_ptr = make_shared<A>(a_vector_);
    }


    const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& getAVec() {
        return a_vector_;
    }

};

int main()
{
    B b;

    b.constructA();

    std::cout << b.getAVec().size() << "\n";
}
```

BUT it wrong, because underlying weak_ptr is "ready" only after function `make_shared` is executed, means only after construction call.
Calling `shared_from_this` or `weak_from_this` is valid only after `make_shared` function is executed.